# Issued a cloudflare SSL Certificate to ubuntu server but SSL gives error

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, cloudflare

I was given a Cloudflare SSL certificate issued by our DNS provider. As the server already has let's encrypt, the domain I had to add is loaded the Cloudflare SSL (when I visit the site I have CERT INVALID & windows does not have enough information to verify the certificate). The SSL came with pem and key file. default-ssl.conf I added the SSL Engine On and added in the paths. It is reading the certificate but not enough information and certificate path is not showing. Please advise.

Comment: Gosh, if there was only some way we could see the error...

Comment: @joeqwerty There is the error "CERT INVALID & windows does not have enough information to verify the certificate"

Comment: It could be anything. Give us the URL of the site so we can see the error for ourselves so that we can try to help.